# Call-flow graph from Python abstract syntax tree

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, compiler

Below is my code for building a call-flow graph from a Python abstract syntax tree. I'm not satisfied with it because the algorithm is very complicated. Perhaps much more complicated than it needs to be. So I want suggestions on how to simplify the algorithm and also on how to make the code more readable.

```
class BasicBlock:
    def __init__(self, insns):
        self.insns = insns

    def type(self):
        return type(self.insns[-1]) if self.insns else None

class CFGBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.succ = defaultdict(list)
        self.bbs = []

    def build_tree(self, nodes):
        buf = []
        for node in nodes:
            tp = type(node)
            if tp in (For, While):
                if buf:
                    yield BasicBlock(buf), []
                yield BasicBlock([node]), [self.build_tree(node.body)]
                buf = []
            elif tp == If:
                buf.append(node)
                branches = [self.build_tree(node.body),
                            self.build_tree(node.orelse)]
                yield BasicBlock(buf), branches
                buf = []
            elif tp in (Break, Continue, Pass, Return):
                buf.append(node)
                yield BasicBlock(buf), []
                return
            elif tp in (Assign, Expr):
                buf.append(node)
            else:
                assert False
        if buf:
            yield BasicBlock(buf), []

    def connect(self, bb_tree, parent_bb, loop_bb):
        tails = []
        breaks = []
        if parent_bb and bb_tree:
            tails = [parent_bb]
        for bb, branches in bb_tree:
            self.bbs.append(bb)
            for tail in tails:
                self.succ[tail].append(bb)
            tp = bb.type()
            if tp == If:
                true_tails, true_breaks = \
                    self.connect(branches[0], bb, loop_bb)
                false_tails, false_breaks = \
                    self.connect(branches[1], bb, loop_bb)
                breaks.extend(true_breaks + false_breaks)
                if not true_tails and not false_tails:
                    return [], breaks
                tails = true_tails + false_tails
                if not branches[1]:
                    tails.append(bb)
            elif tp in (For, While):
                tails, loop_breaks = \
                    self.connect(branches[0], bb, bb)
                for tail in tails:
                    self.succ[tail].append(bb)
                tails = [bb] + loop_breaks
            elif tp == Break:
                if loop_bb:
                    return [], breaks + [bb]
                return [bb], []
            elif tp == Continue:
                if loop_bb:
                    self.succ[bb].append(loop_bb)
                    return [], breaks
                return [bb], []
            elif tp == Return:
                return [], []
            elif tp in (Assign, Expr, Pass, None):
                tails = [bb]
            else:
                assert False
        return tails, breaks

    def build(self, nodes):
        # SSA construction requires an entry block.
        bb_tree = [(BasicBlock([]), [])]
        bb_tree.extend(self.build_tree(nodes))

        # If the last block is a block statement, close the cfg with
        # an empty block.
        if bb_tree[-1][1]:
            dummy = BasicBlock([])
            bb_tree.append((dummy, []))
        self.connect(bb_tree, None, None)
        return self.bbs, self.succ
```

You can run it like this:

```
PROG = '''
for ba in range(10):
    if -(a + 10):
        break
    for y in range(10):
        if not x:
            print('cont from x_99')
            continue
        x = x + 1
        if x:
            if y:
                return x
                pass
            break
        print(x)
print('blah')
while 1:
    if x == 0:
        while x < 10:
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 1
            if x == 5:
                break
            if y == 5:
                continue
            else:
                if y == 2:
                    b = b + 1
                    continue
            a = a + 1
            continue
            print('prutt')
        break
    if b:
        return
        x = 99
    if m:
        while 2:
            if 1:
                break
            else:
                continue
            x = 9
            print('dead code')
        print('this reaches')
print('but ok')
if 2:
    break
else:
    pass
break
print(10)
'''
root = parse(PROG)
builder = CFGBuilder()
bbs, succ = builder.build(root.body)
```

It produces this cfg:

[image]

Here is the [gist for plotting](https://gist.github.com/bjourne/c39779519191a7975fddec75de6c3f72).

Comment: This immediately chokes on `ast.Import`. So like... I'll only verify it with your example source and not realistic source, I guess, because realistic source won't work.

Comment: Correct. It is only supposed to support the basic control flow in the example.

Comment: Where's your `dot` graphing code? It would be useful to include that.

Comment: @Reinderien I added a gist for plotting. Though I don't need help with the plotting code.

Comment: Please include it verbatim in the question body.

Comment: Your edit has also removed your imports, which are important to include.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `from ast import *`; `ast` is already conveniently short as a prefix to a fully-qualified name, and importing splat pollutes your namespace.

Add type hints. This is especially important to understand what on earth your algorithm is doing. In fact, one of your types is recursive! This will likely confuse static analysers like `mypy`, but better to have it than nothing at all.

It's somewhat unidiomatic to pull the type of a variable and then compare that reference to a sequence of other types. The traditional idiomatic way is `isinstance`; the modern way is a `match` specifying your types. In the sample code I demonstrate both.

Don't assert in production code, and especially don't `assert False`. Throw a meaningful exception - for now I have filled this in as `NotImplementedError`.

Avoid line continuation `\` - if multiple lines are necessary (which I don't think they are in your case), prefer parens.

Instead of

```
breaks.extend(true_breaks + false_breaks)
```

which creates an intermediate list only to throw it away, prefer two `extend` calls.

Rather than `branches[0]` or `[1]`, unpack this to a true and false branch. It's more self-documenting, with a bonus that it will catch unexpected sequence lengths.

Don't compare a type to `None` - compare it to `NoneType`. `None` is not of type `None`.

### Suggested

Produces the same output you have; plotting code shoved into a containment function:

```
import ast
from collections import defaultdict
from types import NoneType
from typing import Optional, Type, Iterable, Iterator


class BasicBlock:
    def __init__(self, insns: list[ast.stmt]) -> None:
        self.insns = insns

    @property
    def last(self) -> Optional[ast.stmt]:
        return self.insns[-1] if self.insns else None

    def matches(self, *types: Type[ast.stmt]) -> bool:
        return isinstance(self.last, types)


TreeNode = tuple[
    BasicBlock,
    list[Iterable['TreeNode']]  # this is recursive - yikes
]


class CFGBuilder:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Basic blocks in program order and a mapping of blocks to
        # their successors.
        self.succ: defaultdict[BasicBlock, list[BasicBlock]] = defaultdict(list)
        self.bbs: list[BasicBlock] = []

    def build_tree(self, nodes: list[ast.stmt]) -> Iterator[TreeNode]:
        buf: list[ast.stmt] = []
        
        for node in nodes:
            match node:
                case ast.For() | ast.While():
                    if buf:
                        yield BasicBlock(buf), []
                    yield BasicBlock([node]), [self.build_tree(node.body)]
                    buf = []
        
                case ast.If():
                    buf.append(node)
                    branches = [self.build_tree(node.body),
                                self.build_tree(node.orelse)]
                    yield BasicBlock(buf), branches
                    buf = []
        
                case ast.Break() | ast.Continue() | ast.Pass() | ast.Return():
                    buf.append(node)
                    yield BasicBlock(buf), []
                    return
        
                case ast.Assign() | ast.Expr():
                    buf.append(node)
        
                case other:
                    raise NotImplementedError()
        if buf:
            yield BasicBlock(buf), []

    def connect(
        self,
        bb_tree: Iterable[TreeNode],
        parent_bb: Optional[BasicBlock],
        loop_bb: Optional[BasicBlock],
    ) -> tuple[
        list[BasicBlock],  # tails
        list[BasicBlock],  # breaks
    ]:
        breaks = []

        if parent_bb and bb_tree:
            tails = [parent_bb]
        else:
            tails = []

        for bb, branches in bb_tree:
            self.bbs.append(bb)

            for tail in tails:
                self.succ[tail].append(bb)

            if bb.matches(ast.If):
                true_branch, false_branch = branches
                true_tails, true_breaks = self.connect(true_branch, bb, loop_bb)
                false_tails, false_breaks = self.connect(false_branch, bb, loop_bb)
                breaks.extend(true_breaks)
                breaks.extend(false_breaks)
                if not (true_tails or false_tails):
                    return [], breaks
                tails = true_tails + false_tails
                if not false_branch:
                    tails.append(bb)

            elif bb.matches(ast.For, ast.While):
                branch, = branches
                tails, loop_breaks = self.connect(branch, bb, bb)
                for tail in tails:
                    self.succ[tail].append(bb)
                tails = [bb] + loop_breaks

            elif bb.matches(ast.Break):
                if loop_bb:
                    return [], breaks + [bb]
                return [bb], []

            elif bb.matches(ast.Continue):
                if loop_bb:
                    self.succ[bb].append(loop_bb)
                    return [], breaks
                return [bb], []

            elif bb.matches(ast.Return):
                return [], []

            elif bb.matches(ast.Assign, ast.Expr, ast.Pass, NoneType):
                tails = [bb]

            else:
                raise NotImplementedError()

        return tails, breaks

    def build(self, nodes: list[ast.stmt]) -> tuple[
        list[BasicBlock],
        defaultdict[BasicBlock, list[BasicBlock]],
    ]:
        # SSA construction requires an entry block.
        bb_tree = [(BasicBlock([]), [])]
        bb_tree.extend(self.build_tree(nodes))

        # If the last block is a block statement, close the cfg with
        # an empty block.
        if bb_tree[-1][1]:
            dummy = BasicBlock([])
            bb_tree.append((dummy, []))
        self.connect(bb_tree, None, None)
        return self.bbs, self.succ


def plot():
    from pygraphviz import AGraph
    from re import sub

    COLOR_KWD = '#a020f0'
    COLOR_VAR = '#6c71c4'
    COLOR_STR = '#8b2252'

    def colorize(s, col):
        return '<font color="%s">%s</font>' % (col, s)

    def kwd(s):
        return colorize(s, COLOR_KWD)

    def string(s):
        return colorize(f'&#x27;{s}&#x27;', COLOR_STR)

    OPS_HTML = {
        ast.Not: kwd('not'),
        ast.Add: '+',
        ast.Mult: '*',
        ast.Sub: '-',
        ast.USub: '-'
    }

    OPS_PRECEDENCES = {
        ast.Add: 0,
        ast.Sub: 0,
        ast.Mult: 1
    }

    def htmlify(node):
        tp = type(node)
        if tp == ast.If:
            return kwd('if') + ' ' + htmlify(node.test)
        elif tp == ast.Assign:
            targets = ', '.join([htmlify(t) for t in node.targets])
            value = htmlify(node.value)
            return f'{targets} &larr; {value}'
        if tp == ast.BinOp:
            left = node.left
            right = node.right
            left_html = htmlify(left)
            right_html = htmlify(right)
            if type(left) == ast.BinOp and OPS_PRECEDENCES[type(left.op)] == 0:
                left_html = f'({left_html})'
            if type(right) == ast.BinOp:
                right_html = f'({right_html})'
            return ' '.join([
                left_html, htmlify(node.op), right_html
            ])
        elif tp == ast.UnaryOp:
            operand = node.operand
            operand_html = htmlify(operand)
            if type(operand) == ast.BinOp:
                if OPS_PRECEDENCES[type(operand.op)] == 0:
                    operand_html = f'({operand_html})'
            op_html = htmlify(node.op)
            if type(node.op) == ast.Not:
                op_html += ' '
            return op_html + operand_html
        elif tp in OPS_HTML:
            return OPS_HTML[tp]
        elif tp == ast.For:
            return ' '.join([
                kwd('for'), htmlify(node.target),
                kwd('in'), htmlify(node.iter)
            ])
        elif tp == ast.While:
            return kwd('while') + ' ' + htmlify(node.test)
        elif tp == ast.Compare:
            assert len(node.ops) == 1
            return ' '.join([
                htmlify(node.left), htmlify(node.ops[0]),
                htmlify(node.comparators[0])
            ])
        elif tp == ast.Expr:
            return htmlify(node.value)
        elif tp == ast.Eq:
            return '='
        elif tp == ast.Lt:
            return '&lt;'
        elif tp == ast.Name:
            id = node.id
            s = f'<i>{id}</i>'
            if '_' in id:
                s = sub(r'(\w+)_(\d+|\?)', r'<i>\1</i><sub>\2</sub>', id)
            return colorize(s, COLOR_VAR)
        elif tp == ast.Constant:
            value = node.value
            if type(value) == str:
                return string(value)
            return str(value)
        elif tp == ast.Num:
            return str(node.n)
        elif tp == ast.Str:
            return string(node.s)
        elif tp == ast.Subscript:
            value_html = htmlify(node.value)
            slice_html = htmlify(node.slice)
            return f'{value_html}&#91;{slice_html}&#93;'
        elif tp == ast.Index:
            return htmlify(node.value)
        elif tp == ast.Call:
            id = node.func.id
            args = ', '.join(htmlify(a) for a in node.args)
            # Phis are so special we pretend that they are keywords
            if id == 'phi':
                return ' '.join([kwd('phi'), args])
            return f'{id}({args})'
        elif tp in (ast.Break, ast.Continue, ast.Pass):
            return kwd(str(tp.__name__).lower())
        elif tp == ast.Return:
            s = kwd('return')
            if node.value:
                return s + ' ' + htmlify(node.value)
            return s
        else:
            assert False

    def plot_bbs(bbs, succ):
        G = AGraph(strict=False, directed=True)
        graph_attrs = {
            'dpi': 300,
            'ranksep': 0.3,
            'fontname': 'Inconsolata',
            'bgcolor': 'transparent'
        }
        G.graph_attr.update(graph_attrs)
        node_attrs = {
            'shape': 'box',
            'width': 0.55,
            'style': 'filled',
            'fillcolor': 'white'
        }
        G.node_attr.update(node_attrs)
        edge_attrs = {
            'fontsize': '10pt'
        }
        G.edge_attr.update(edge_attrs)
        names = {bb: i for i, bb in enumerate(bbs)}

        # Add nodes and edges.
        for bb, name in names.items():
            edges = succ[bb]
            peri = 2 if bb == bbs[0] or not edges else 1
            lines = [htmlify(node) for node in bb.insns]
            label = ''.join(l + '<br align="left"/>' for l in lines)
            label = f'<{label}>'
            G.add_node(name, label=label, peripheries=peri)

            colors = ['black'] * len(edges)
            if len(edges) == 2:
                colors = ['#00aa00', '#aa0000']
            for bb2, color in zip(edges, colors):
                G.add_edge(names[bb], names[bb2], color=color)

        G.draw('test.png', prog='dot')

    return plot_bbs


def main() -> None:
    root = ast.parse('''
for ba in range(10):
    if -(a + 10):
        break
    for y in range(10):
        if not x:
            print('cont from x_99')
            continue
        x = x + 1
        if x:
            if y:
                return x
                pass
            break
        print(x)
print('blah')
while 1:
    if x == 0:
        while x < 10:
            x = x + 1
            y = y + 1
            if x == 5:
                break
            if y == 5:
                continue
            else:
                if y == 2:
                    b = b + 1
                    continue
            a = a + 1
            continue
            print('prutt')
        break
    if b:
        return
        x = 99
    if m:
        while 2:
            if 1:
                break
            else:
                continue
            x = 9
            print('dead code')
        print('this reaches')
print('but ok')
if 2:
    break
else:
    pass
break
print(10)
''')
    builder = CFGBuilder()
    bbs, succ = builder.build(root.body)
    plot()(bbs, succ)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. Though plotting is not part of my problem so you dont have to include that.